# What's the proper usage of Fibers in Windows for C?

Tags: c, windows, fibers

I have been recently interested about Fibers in Windows, but I have hard time using it. The documentation involves function definitions and some example, but still some stuff are not clear to me. I see that `CreateFiber` definition is defined as:

```
LPVOID CreateFiber(
  SIZE_T                dwStackSize,
  LPFIBER_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  LPVOID                lpParameter
);
```

So, we specify the stack size, the function for the fiber and possibly a parameter for the function. Now, my questions are:

1) Once fiber is created, I assume the provided functions execution doesn't immediately start, right? I believe one needs to call `ConvertThreadToFiber` first. But are there any other stuff needed to be done? I mean in the simplest case, how does defining, initiating, running and deleting a simple fiber looks like?

2) Is it possible somehow to check whether we are actually in the fiber? I mean whether fiber is executing inside some other part of the app? If yes, how?

3) Is it possible to get the memory location of the fiber's stack and the actual content of the fiber's stack at any moment we wish? If yes, how?

Comment: It's important to ask one specific question at a time. You've opened up three very broad subjects here.

Comment: @tadman I though because they are all related, I should just combine them. But, sorry. I can edit and remove the last two if you want.

Comment: Each one is probably fine on its own, but this is asking a lot to cover in one shot. What's the goal here? Understanding fibers more thoroughly, or do you have a specific problem you're trying to solve and you think fibers might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I've only written a few test programs that use fibers in order to verify that they were working properly while running under a performance profiler that I was working on at the time.)

1) As you say, a fiber does not run by itself. It only runs when another thread explicitly switches to it by calling `SwitchToFiber`. Execution then continues on that fiber until *it* calls `SwitchToFiber` and switches back to the original thread or another fiber.

2) It's unclear to me what you are asking here. If the fiber is the only one calling a particular function it can set some variable or call a function and you'll know it was there. If multiple fibers are calling the same function, maybe they could record their thread id and you'd be able to infer which fiber called the function. What's the use case here?

3) If the fiber is executing, it has access to its stack/registers in the normal way. I am not aware of a way to arbitrarily access the stack of a fiber that isn't currently scheduled to run on a thread, but I suppose you could record the address of the stack from within the fiber itself.

For what it's worth, I don't think the fiber support in Windows API is used much.

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
1) So, basically we always need two threads when using a fiber, so we can switch between them?
2) My question is just, whether there are some functions or anything that I can call, which can tell me, yes there is a fiber running at the moment, or yes, this fiber is active.
3) Yes that's what I'm asking, are there any methods or anything to get the stack address of the fiber?

Comment: You don't strictly need multiple threads to use fibers. Fibers are essentially alternate stacks for a thread - possibly the main thread. When you switch fibers you essentially switch stacks. And, as mentioned above, when a fiber is executing it has access to its own stack in the normal way.

Comment: Aha I see. Thanks for clarification. So, basically if one fiber is active, and then I declare a local variable at that moment, the variable will be written on the stack of this fiber, right? And afterwards if I switch to another fiber, it won't be in the stack of this second fiber, or?

Comment: Correct. Each fiber has its own stack, hence its own copy of local variables.

Comment: “copy of local variables”, can we make sure that some data is only in one stack and not the other, something like private to one?

Comment: Since each fiber has its own stack, each fiber has its own copy of local variables, not visible to other fibers (unless you explicitly create pointers to them and pass those around).

Comment: But, how can I get the total size of the fiber stack? I can get the low and high addresses using `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` once the fiber is active.

Comment: You specify that yourself when you create the fiber.